# How to define if a string is date or datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, time

I have incoming string, for instance `12.10.03 00:00:00.0000000`. How to define if there is `time` in this string or just `date`?

Note that, `date` and `time` can have different formats. For example:

- date can be `January 03, 2012`
- time can be `1:1`

Comment: There is a time in it, midnight exactly. Are you wanting to exclude all strings when it is midnight?

Comment: I want to know is there any time specified in the string

Comment: Is using a CLR function an option?  Might be your best bet, you could either run a Regex or take advantage of stronger typing available in the CLR

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't return zero there is time:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,@VariableOrColumn,CAST(@VariableOrColumn AS DATE))
```

Add more precision for DATETIME2(7) by adding nano seconds if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can take like this:

```
SELECT x = SUBSTRING('12.10.03 00:00:00.0000000', 1, 8);
```

Edit code for different formats;

```
SUBSTRING('12.10.03 00:00:00.0000000', 1,CHARINDEX(' ','12.10.03 00:00:00.0000000'));
```

Comment: Firtsly you should convert your time. You can use CONVERT() function. After convert it, add it in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator;

```
if (@MyString like '%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX( '%:%','12.10.03 00:00:00.0000000')> 0 THEN 'datetime'
            ELSE 'Date' END AS Result
```

and to validate a date you can use [ISDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function.

Comment: date and time can have different format, time can looks like 1:02

Answer (score 0):

First cast your string as datetime to put it in a proper format then just cast the resulting datetime as time and compare it with midnight as time and viola:

```
Select Case when Cast(Cast(@yourstring as datetime) as Time) = Cast('00:00:00.0000000' as time) then Cast(@yourstring as date) else Cast(@yourstring as datetime) end
```

Answer (score 0):

if(@x='12.10.03').it is valid datetime and time is 00:00:00

if(@x='12.10.03 00:00:00.0000000').it is valid datetime and time is again 00:00:00
So what do you mean by saying if it contain time.

you can test this script thoroughly with different input .I tested and its running fine .

```
BEGIN TRY
declare @x varchar(32) = '12.10.03 00:00:00.0000000'
-- or '12.10.03' or '00:00:00.0000000' or '0000000' or 'fgdfgg'
Declare @outputdt datetime2(7)
Declare @hr int
Declare @minute int
Declare @sec int
set @outputdt=@x
--select @outputdt
if isdate(LEFT(@x, 21))=1
BEGIN

        select LEFT(@x, 21)
        select @hr=DATEPART(hour,@outputdt)
        ,@minute=DATEPART(minute,@outputdt)
        ,@sec=DATEPART(minute,@outputdt)
END
else
    BEGIN
    select @hr=DATEPART(hour,@outputdt)
        ,@minute=DATEPART(minute,@outputdt)
        ,@sec=DATEPART(minute,@outputdt)
    select 'Not valid1'
   END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 select 'not valid'
END CATCH

select @hr,@minute

if(@hr>0)
select 'Todo'
```

Answer (score 0):

After some r&d , I do this and I think this will help you.

You are not mention Sql version, so this sample will work `SQLSERVER2008` and above

For more info :- 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/12/sql-server-get-date-and-time-from-current-datetime-sql-in-sixty-seconds-025-video/

```
declare @s nvarchar(200) = '12.10.03' -- 00:00:00.0000000'

--select CONVERT(time, @s) 

Select 
    case 
        when isdate(@s ) = 1 
        then 
            case 
                when CONVERT(time, @s) = '00:00:00.0000000'
                then 'no time'
                else 'it has time'
                end         
        else 
           'no time'
        end
        as dateHaveTimeOrNOT

set @s = '12.10.03 01:20:00'

Select cast (@s as date) , isdate(@s ),CONVERT(time, @s),
    case 
        when isdate(@s ) = 1 
        then 
            case 
                when CONVERT(time, @s) = '00:00:00.0000000'
                then 'no time'
                else 'it has time'
                end         
        else 
           'no time'
        end
        as dateHaveTimeOrNOT
```